# Data.IORef vs Recursion

Tags: variables, haskell, recursion, io, reference

### Data.IORef

```
keepRunning <- newIORef True
let loop = do
    running <- readIORef keepRunning
    if running then
        do
            {- Do stuff -}
            loop running
            return ()
    else
        do
            {- Do stuff -}
            return ()
```

---

### Recursion

```
let keepRunning = True
let loop running = if running then
    do
        {- Do stuff -}
        loop running
        return ()
    else do
        {- Do stuff -}
        return ()
loop keepRunning
```

---

Is there any reason to prefer one of the above methods above the other? Will the `do` blocks containing recursion slow the program down compared to outside the do block? If you can replace every instance of `Data.IORef` with a function, then why does `Data.IORef` even exist?

Comment: You can not "replace every instance of Data.IORef with a function" -- why do you believe that? In some simple cases you can, but generally you can not. Perhaps it might be true that you can perform a whole-program transformation to eliminate all the `IORef`s, but the transformation is not local, and requires a lot of state-passing.

Comment: `IORef` is useful with concurrency. I also recently used it with some FFI code whose API demanded I pass some callback `:: Foo -> IO ()` to be called multiple times (so the `IORef` was used for keeping track of state). Reasons not to use it when recursion would suffice are all the same reasons why implicit state makes programs more confusing, error-prone, difficult to refactor, etc.

Answer (score 3):

If your `{- Do stuff -}` in your first version directly assigns `keepRunning` to the result of some computation, you can of course rewrite it easily to make that computation the condition for the recursion and get rid of the `IORef`. That would be the preferable solution.

However, if your first version sets `keepRunning` inside some other function, the equivalent ref-less version could become quite a bit more complicated. So which version is preferable would be less clear in that case. Though you could make the point that such a thing would be bad design in the first place. It's hard to say anything specific without knowing what `{- Do stuff -}` actually does.

> Will the do blocks containing recursion slow the program down compared to outside the do block?

No.

> If you can replace every instance of Data.IORef with a function, then why does Data.IORef even exist?

Depending on the APIs you work with, you might not be able to (say you have event handlers in a non-FRP GUI library). Further there are cases where you could remove IORef, but only by hurting performance and/or making code more complicated.

That said your example of using an `IORef` as a loop condition is one where you could almost certainly write a better version without `IORef`.

Comment: Inside the dostuff, that is

Comment: @YoYoYonnY It does actually - my mistake. I guess I assumed that the `running` in `loop running` was supposed to refer to the same variable `running` that you received as a parameter. But you're right, if you reuse the same name for a different variable, the code can terminate. However that makes having a parameter pretty pointless in the first place - you could just as well wrap an `if` around the recursive call.

Comment: Yes... I just thought this would be a better demonstration because the two are so similair.

Comment: `running <- return False`, slightly different.